# (Nonlinear after Linear)-Differential Equations

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, diffeomorphism

I know the theory needed to solve nonhomogeneous linear differential equations looking like
$$\dot{x}(t) = A(t)x + b(t)\tag{1}$$
in finite-dimensional spaces.

Let $A(t)$ be a linear form, i.e. mapping into $\mathbb{R}$, and $b$ be real-valued. If I have a monotonous smooth diffeomorphism $\varphi\in\operatorname{Diff}^\infty(\mathbb{R},[0,1])$, how does solving $(1)$ relate to solving the possibly non-linear differential equation
$$\dot{x}(t) = \varphi\left(A(t)x + b(t)\right),\tag{2}$$
in terms of solvability, stability etc. Do the solutions of $(1)$ and $(2)$ relate at all?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Even in the case where $\varphi(X) = \Phi X$ is linear, we can still get drastic changes in the behavior of solutions, since $\Phi A$ can have very different eigenvalues/vectors than $A$. In the nonlinear case, solvability of $\varphi(Ax+b)$ is more dependent on the solvability of $\varphi(x)$.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 Thank you for your comment. Note that if $\varphi$ was linear, it would essentially be just a number so eigenvalues/vectors would only be scaled, right? Also, $\varphi$ wouldn't be bounded. I am talking specifically about the smooth, monotonous $\mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$ case, so I hoped one could say something, anything... Still, I expected the answer being along your lines to be the more probable case.